# In c#, can a class inherit an interface?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, interface

I know that an interface inherits another interface, and a class can inherit from another interface, but can a class inherit from another interface?

Comment: `a class can inherit from another interface, but can a class inherit from another interface`? I don't understand your question.

Comment: "and a class can inherit from another interface, but can a class inherit from another interface".. .welcome to the tautology club

Comment: MSDN example that shows how to implement interfaces: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually asking here.

Comment: You implement not inherit interfaces

Comment: ok might it be that you are asking: if Class A implements an interface I_A and Class B inherits from Class A -> would it also inherit the interface I_A ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Interfaces are meant to be implemented by classes.** when you declare an interface you expect to work with an instance that implements it - that instance must be a class, since you cannot instantiate interfaces.

The case when you declare an interface which inherits from a different interface is possible, and allows you to separate the responsibility of each interface, but force a class to implement all of those responsibilities

As mentioned in my comment on the question, MSDN example for implementing interfaces [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's called "implementing" the interface.

If `interface Inter1{}` and `class A : Inter1`, then if `class B : A`, class `B` will also "inherit" the interface `Inter1`.

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft's [Inheritance (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx)

> A class or struct can implement multiple interfaces. A class can inherit a base class and also implement one or more interfaces.

So, a class:

- can implement multiple interfaces (no limits)
- inherits from a base class (just the one. If none is declared, the base class is object by default)

Comment: *All* classes ultimately inherit from Object. The fact that an object is also inheriting from another class doesn't change that fact. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx -

Comment: But only a single base class. I'll change my answer to empashise this.

Comment: The ultimate base class is *always* System.Object, regardless of any other facts about your object hierarchy.

Comment: Very correct. We _could_ make many statements about the transitive nature of inheritance and implementations. I don't find any of these observations relevant here.